# How to parse PostgreSQL configuration file in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, parsing, configuration-files

Python has ConfigParser library for parsing mysql configuration files.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

But i need to parse configuration files of PostgreSQL as well. But i couldn't find any parser for them.

In PostgreSQL there is no section or heading, so it can't be done by `configparser`.

Example:

```
# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

data_directory = '/data/postgresql'        # use data in another directory
                    # (change requires restart)
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf'    # host-based authentication file
                    # (change requires restart)
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ident.conf'    # ident configuration file
                    # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.1-main.pid'        # write an extra PID file
                    # (change requires restart)
```

I was using the below code for mysql and it's working fine but not for postgresql.conf file.

```
import ConfigParser

class MysqlParserModule:

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Mysql Parser Module'

    def parse_option(self, conf_file, section, option):
        try:
            config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
            config.read(conf_file)
            result = config.get(section, option)
            print "'%s' value is '%s' under '%s' section" % (option, result, section)
        except Exception as ex:
            print 'in parse_option exception'
            print ex

    def test(self):
        test = MysqlParserModule()
        conf_file = '/root/Desktop/db_config/my_new.cnf'
        section = 'client'
        option = 'port'

        test.parse_option(conf_file, section, option)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = MysqlParserModule()
    test.test()
```

Comment: Show us an example of the files you want to parse.

Comment: You can find sample file here. I'm also using this.

http://www.techforce.com.br/news/linux_blog/postgresql_tuning_example#.U75uHVSSy-I

Comment: OK, I've edited your question to include the file you want to parse. Now please include the Python code you have tried to parse this file.

Comment: Please **edit your question**. Don't put code in a comment.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried to parse a PostgreSQL config file. We already know that `configparser` doesn't work.

Comment: oh! though i couldn't fine any library, so i was hoping for any library or something that i can use and start making parser for postgresq :(

Comment: SO is for questions about *your* code. Questions asking for a library or other resource are closed as off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure that, is there any library available or not so i didn't mention 'library' in question. Do u have any other idea to do the parsing?

Comment: postgres 9.4 has set and show commands for the postgresql.auto.conf file.  it doesn't parse the file, but, you can get and set most of the values. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-altersystem.html